# Rails ActiveRecord include non-related tables into query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have model `Benchmark`. It has method `scores` which is doing some calculations. 
During this calculations, it uses all values from table `Synonyms`. It has the corresponding model, but these models (`Benchmark` and `Synonym`) are not related to each other. I always need *all* synonyms in any of my benchmark calculation. Synonyms are used to replace values in a couple of strings which are Benchmark attributes.
To get the synonyms I simply use the `Synonym.all` method inside my `scores` method:

```
  def scores
    @synonyms ||= Hash[Synonym.all.map {|synonym| [synonym.synonym, synonym.word]}]
    @scores ||= # replacing substrings in Benchmark name using synonyms
  end
```

So far so good. But now I want to perform bulk calculations for all the benchmarks I have. This obviously leads to N+1 query problem — each `scores` method calls `Synonym.all` method. Rails is smart enough to cache this query and avoid tons of DB queries but I'm still wondering is there some way to tell ActiveRecord that all my Benchmarks always include all Synonyms? I can't use belongs_to/has_many/etc because my tables are not linked.

One of the solutions I've used in the similar case was to fetch `Synonym.all`, then fetch `Benchmark.includes(:...).all`, and then inject synonyms manually into each benchmark, like `benchmarks.each {|b| b.synonyms = @synonyms}` but I'm looking for more elegant approach.

I use Rails 5.

Comment: _"doing some calculations using synonyms"_ - can you show what they are?

Comment: Calculations are a bit complex and I believe they're not related to questions, but synonyms are used to replace some values in string which is loaded along with benchmark. I'll add this clarification into question.